# Storing and using Cookie in WebView

Tags: android, cookies

Hi not sure what I'm asking as I've not worked with cookies before. In my app I'm opening a WebView and we submit some data and I want to store the cookie, that way when I close the WebView(also close app) and re-open it uses the stored cookie.

I'm not too sure what my code is doing currently as I've been following examples.

```
@Override
        public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) 
findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            progressBar.setIndeterminate(true);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
            String cookieStr = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
            try {
                storeCookies(url, cookieStr);
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        private void storeCookies(String url, String cookieString) throws URISyntaxException {
            if (cookieString !=null &&  !cookieString.isEmpty()) {
                URI uri = new URI(url);
                List<HttpCookie> cookies = HttpCookie.parse(cookieString);
                for (HttpCookie cookie : cookies) {
                    cookieStore = new CookieStore() {
                        @Override
                        public void add(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
                            cookieStore.add(uri, cookie);
                        }


                        @Override
                        public List<HttpCookie> get(URI uri) {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public List<HttpCookie> getCookies() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public List<URI> getURIs() {
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean remove(URI uri, HttpCookie cookie) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean removeAll() {
                            return false;
                        }
                    };

                }
            }
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
            ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            setURL(url);

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: go to https://medium.com/@elye.project/a-tale-on-android-cookies-store-management-b04832ca18c6

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for setting the cookies for a site, follow this code.

**Kotlin:**

```
val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true)
cookieManager.setCookie("YOUR_WEBSITE_URL", "key=value")
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   val cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this)
   cookieSyncManager.sync()
}
```

**Java:**

```
CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance();
cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true);
cookieManager.setCookie("YOUR_WEBSITE_URL", "key=value");
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
   CookieSyncManager cookieSyncManager = CookieSyncManager.createInstance(this);
   cookieSyncManager.sync();
}
```

Replace **YOUR_WEBSITE_URL** with your website url and **key=value** pair with values. Hope this helps.